# Enabling wireless tools on Android

Tags: ad-hoc-networks

I need to use commands like iwconfig in Android, I know I have to install the wireless tools because they are not in Android by default, The problem is that I have just seen 3 chinesse tutorials that makes no sense when I translate them, and a link that downloads a directory with Android wireless tools, but I don't know what to do to get them into my device and use them.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download [wireless_tools.30.pre9.tar.gz](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html).
   This version supports non-ASCII char in ESSID.
2. Unpack it into *mydroid/external/wireless-tools* directory.
3. Create *Android.mk* file with the following content:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
   ################## build iwlib ###################
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iwlib.c
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Winline -MMD -fPIC
   LOCAL_MODULE:= libiw
   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc libm
   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
   ################## build iwconfig #################
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iwconfig.c
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Winline -MMD -fPIC
   LOCAL_MODULE:= iwconfig
   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc libm libiw
   #LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
   LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES) # install to system/xbin
   #LOCAL_UNSTRIPPED_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_UNSTRIPPED)
   #LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng user
   include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
   ################## build iwlist ###################
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := iwlist.c iwlib.h
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Winline -MMD -fPIC
   LOCAL_MODULE:= iwlist
   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc libm libiw
   #LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
   LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES) # install to system/xbin
   #LOCAL_UNSTRIPPED_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_UNSTRIPPED)
   #LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng user
   include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
   ```
4. Modify it as follows:

   - Change *wireless.22.h* to be *wireless.h* ;
   - Modify *ifrename.c* , add *getline()* function. You can get the code from *external/genext2fs/genext2fs.c* ;
     Notice that this file uses macro to pass another function to *getline()* .
   - Modify *iwlib.h* ,  change #include to be #include .
     [You might need to check the original file to know what the author means]
5. Compile

   ```
   ~/eclair-21/external/wireless-tools$ . ../../build/envsetup.sh
   ~/eclair-21/external/wireless-tools/wireless-tools$ mm
   ```
6. Copy files to the system

   ```
   ~/eclair-21/external/wireless-tools$ croot
   ~/eclair-21$ cp out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/iwconfig /nfs/rootfs/system/xbin/iwconfig
   ~/eclair-21$ cp out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/iwlist /nfs/rootfs/system/xbin/
   ```
7. Test
   After starting Android:

   ```
   # modprobe libertas
   # modprobe libertas_sdio
   libertas_sdio: Libertas SDIO driver
   libertas_sdio: Copyright Pierre Ossman
   model=0xb
   sd8686_helper.bin sd8686.bin
   init: untracked pid 853 exited
   init: untracked pid 856 exited
   libertas: eth1: Marvell WLAN 802.11 adapter
   # iwconfig eth1                
   eth1      IEEE 802.11b/g  ESSID:"Antrose-11g"
             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:15:E9:0C:87:7C
             Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=13 dBm
             Retry limit:8   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B
             Encryption key:off
             Power Management:off
             Link Quality=83/100  Signal level=-60 dBm  Noise level=-93 dBm
             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:1441
             Tx excessive retries:44  Invalid misc:11220   Missed beacon:0
   # iwlist scan
   eth1      Scan completed :
             Cell 01 - Address: 00:22:6B:8C:5D:3A
                       ESSID:"Antrose-11g"
                       Mode:Managed
                       Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                       Quality=65/100  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=-96 dBm
                       Encryption key:off
                       Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                                 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
   # iwconfig eth1 essid Antrose-11g
   # iwconfig eth1                
   eth1      IEEE 802.11b/g  ESSID:"Antrose-11g"
             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:15:E9:0C:87:7C
             Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=13 dBm
             Retry limit:8   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B
             Encryption key:off
             Power Management:off
             Link Quality=83/100  Signal level=-60 dBm  Noise level=-93 dBm
             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:1441
             Tx excessive retries:44  Invalid misc:11220   Missed beacon:0
   ```
8. Done.

Ref: 
http://anemospring.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-wireless-tools.html

Comment: An answer which contains little more than a raw link to another site is not an answer. Readers shouldn't be forced to go to another site to get the information they need. That's why your previous answer just like this one was deleted. At _best_ this is a comment.

Comment: See: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/906/are-answers-that-are-just-links-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am a newbie here. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Nicely done. Now _that's_ an answer!

Comment: Thank You, but, is this really gonna work in an Android device? how can I access to mydroid directory? This really helped a lot, but I still have some doubts about what to do.

Comment: I think that is the directory contains the Android source code. Essentially you need to compile this tool under the system source code directory and copy it into your phone. Based on my own experience, you might need to ensure that the version of that Android source is the same as the version of system in your phone.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this line: `Modify iwlib.h , change #include to be #include . [You might need to check the original file to know what the author means]`

Comment: I did the translation, but this tutorial was not mine. In the original post (see the ref link above), it is likely that the author made a typo here.