# get wireless tools in Android devices?

Tags: wi-fi, linux, kernel, ad-hoc-networks

i see this  [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/enabling-wireless-tools-on-android) about enable wireless tools on android.

but i can't understand the way he follow to enable tools on what terminal or adb shells for the device or on linux platform !!

also from where can i have this directory `mydroid/external/wireless-tools directory`,  it is for the android device or for linux file directory ?

and the compile and build from where !!!

Answer (score 0):

[Wireless Tools home page](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) has links to multiple versions including:

- [latest stable (v29)](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/wireless_tools.29.tar.gz)
- [latest beta (v30-pre9)](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/wireless_tools.30.pre9.tar.gz)

Comment: keep down with the exclamation marks. I am done with trying to help someone who does not want to be helped.