# Nexus 7: Can I set its WiFi to monitor/promiscous mode? If so, how?

Tags: nexus-7

Related question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21057/nexus-7-or-any-other-good-android-tablets-for-pen-testing

I need to turn a Nexus 7 with Android in it into a wireless packet sniffer. I need to keep track not only of my own traffic but also of the traffic my WiFi interface can capture (hence the need to set it in monitor mode)

I've installed the Cyanogen mod to gain root's access so that's not a problem. It also has [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) to get some command line tools. Heck, I even compiled wireless-tools (following [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/enabling-wireless-tools-on-android) thread)

I'm not even certain that even doable with the embedded wireless *card* in the Nexus 7 allows monitor mode? If it does, would it be possible setting it using regular commands (such as `iwconfig`, `ifconfig`) I'm old, and that's what I'm used to **:-D** (opening a terminal and typing things)

The about tablet says:

```
Kenel version: 3.4.0-cyanogenmod-gb7efce1
               build03@cyanogenmod #1
               Mon Feb 3 15:26:37 PST 2014
CPU:           ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7)
CyaongenMod version: 10.2.1.-flo
```

I know it only has a WiFi interface (no 3G/4G) and also that it's a 2013 model Since my Wi-Fi's MAC address starts with `AC:22:0B`, I guess I have some kind of `ASUSTek` card, but I haven't been able to find the specific model.

Thank you in advance.

**PS:** If I can't monitor wireless traffic with a Nexus 7, I'm open to buy a new tablet with a network interface that accepts monitoring. I'm open to suggestions about what to get.

Comment: try this http://intohand.com/blog/post/nexus-7-a-hackers-toolkit.-part-1-setup-and-hacking-wpa-networks