# Root Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm continuing my quest on turning an Android device into a WiFi sniffer (see [Nexus 7: Can I set its WiFi to monitor/promiscous mode? If so, how?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67236/nexus-7-can-i-set-its-wifi-to-monitor-promiscous-mode-if-so-how) ) I found an unused Galaxy Tab 3 (model [SM-T210R](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T210RZWYXAR)) so I'd like to try that one.

First step, rooting it, right? Well... it turns out to be a was more difficult task than I imagined... [Cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices) doesn't have a version for Galaxy Tab 3.

With a bit of apprehension I tried installing this one: http://techbeasts.com/2014/01/19/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7-0-sm-t210t210r/
but when the Galaxy tries to install the from the .zip, I get:

```
Verifying update package...
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:signature verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

which, according to the comments of that teachbeasts.com page, seems to be a pretty common issue.

Has anyone successfully rooted a Galaxy Tab 3? If so, could you point me to the web or resource where you found the method?

PS: If you did successfully root it, you still have money in your bank account, right? I'm kind of wary about flashing my device with a *who-knows-from-where* image...

Thank you in advance!